# How to load another UIViewController to a UIView Example Like UITabbarController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a 2 UIViewController(s), I need to be able to change the views at the bottom of the Airtime and Data Plan Upon tap gesture on Airtime and Data Plan!
The yellow line will indicate the active view controller. some thing like tab bar.
[Perhaps, the image attached is an android version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Kbjy.png)

Could anyone provide a help on how to go about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally use a library called ICVIewPager

https://github.com/iltercengiz/ICViewPager

This is pretty simple and easy to use with examples. It should put you in the right direction without writing a lot of code.

Comment: ICViewPager is similar but not exactly what I need

Comment: As far as i understand the question, ICViewPager should fit the bill, you can tap on the tabs to change the viewcontroller (swipe works too). If you want to further enhance it, you can modify its classes. What is your custom requirement?

Comment: Ok I should try not to be lazy!